# get current extent of mapview (R, in Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, android-mapview

I have a small Shiny app - code below. The idea is that a user is able to edit, add and delete points and polygons. Because the end products will be two shapefiles (one points, one polygons), I need to keep the data separate (and it is very likely that they will have different attributes, in any case, so pulling them together into one dataset is not an option).

My solution is to have the mapview generate each time depending on what the user has selected to edit. I'm very pleased this works fine - but the extent of the map view is reset to the extent of the data every time this happens. I would like to find some way to capture the current extent before the update, so that I can then use it in `setView` to keep the same extent. Is there a way to do this? Mapview doesn't appear to have this functionality, and I'm not sure how I could maybe talk to Leaflet to achieve it from this point.

Any help appreciated.

App:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(mapedit)
library(mapview)
library(sp)

workSpace <- "C:/temp"
myPoints <<- readOGR(workSpace,"Points")
myPolys <<- readOGR(workSpace,"Polys")

## Remove a few unneccesary attributes (for this exercise, anyway):
myPolys$Shape_Leng <- NULL
myPolys$Shape_Area <- NULL
myPoints$Shape_Leng <- NULL
myPoints$Shape_Area <- NULL
myPolys$OBJECTID <- NULL
myPoints$OBJECTID <- NULL

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type= "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  editModUI("test-edit", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top=10, right=10,width=300,
                wellPanel(style = "opacity: 0.80",
                          fluidRow(
                            tags$div(title = "Title",
                                   tags$h4("Select Edit Layer")
                            )
                          ),
                          fluidRow(
                            radioButtons(inputId = "layerChoice", label = NULL, choices = list("Polys" = 1, "Points" = 2))
                          )
                )
  )
)

server <-  function(input, output, session) {
  cntr_coords <- c(mean(coordinates(myPolys)[,1]), mean(coordinates(myPolys)[,2]))
  myMap <<- (mapview(myPolys) + mapview(myPoints))@map %>% setView(cntr_coords[1], cntr_coords[2], zoom = 17)
  result <- callModule(editMod, "test-edit", myMap, "myPolys")

  observeEvent(input$layerChoice, {
    if (input$layerChoice == 1)
    {
      result <- callModule(editMod, "test-edit", myMap, "myPolys")
    }
    else
    {
      result <- callModule(editMod, "test-edit", myMap, "myPoints")
    }
  })

  observe({req(result()$finished)
    ## Code here to save edits
    showModal(modalDialog(title = "Confirm save", 
                          "Do you want to save your edit?",
                          footer = tagList(
                            modalButton("Cancel"),
                            actionButton("ok", "OK")
                          )))
  })

  observeEvent(input$ok, {
    ## Write the data to the existing data
    ## firstly get the result.
    newData <- result()$finished
    if (input$layerChoice == 1) {

      ## Coerce into spatial data frame
      newPoly <- as(newData, "Spatial")
      ## Add required columns and give them a value (this will become a menu)
      newPoly$NAME <- "NewName"
      newPoly$CODE <- "CodeNEW"
      newPoly$Attrib1 <- "New Attrib"
      newPoly$Attrib2 <- 8888

      ## Drop the attributes we don't want
      newPoly$X_leaflet_id <- NULL
      newPoly$feature_type <- NULL

      ## Now merge with the existing data
      myPolys <<- rbind(myPolys, newPoly)
    }
    else
    {
      newPoint <- as(newData, "Spatial")
      ## Add required columns etc
      newPoint$NAME <- "NewPointName"
      newPoint$CODE <- "CodePt"

      ## Drop the attributes we don't want
      newPoint$X_leaflet_id <- NULL
      newPoint$feature_type <- NULL

      ## Now merge with the existing data
      myPoints <<- rbind(myPoints, newPoint)
    }
    ## Refresh the map
    myMap <<- (mapview(myPolys) + mapview(myPoints))@map
    ## Close the menu
    removeModal()
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My data files are here but are easily reproduced:

[Points](https://kvisit.com/PA/uJkB)
[Polys](https://kvisit.com/PA/uZkB)